# What happens when a static variable is set to null while it's being enumerated in a method

Tags: c#, multithreading

Given the following class and assuming print list takes a long time to run, what would happen if thread 1 calls PrintList() and then while it's running, Thread 2 called ClearList?

We're not modifying the collection just changing the reference to point at a different location in the heap. So does the enumeration continue to work? If so is this because a copy of the _someList reference gets put on the stack frame for the method?

```
public class foo()
{

    private static List<string> _someList;

    public void ClearList()
    {
        _someList = null;
    }

    public void PrintList()
    {
        foreach(var item in _someList)
        {
            Console.Print(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Even if your enumeration continues to work, relying on this kind of behavior sounds dangerous to say the least. Your code shouldn't be setting a variable to null if you think something else is using it. If there are cases you're worried about, you should handle them specifically

Comment: I agree this isn't something you would want to do in your code. I was just interested to hear what the answer was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of two very predictable things will happen.  At some point in time the first thread will evaluate the varaible `_someList` to its value, a reference to a list.  If that happens before the second thread clears it, then it will iterate through that list and print the results.  If the second thread happens to clear the list before it gets to the `foreach` loop then you'll get a null reference exception.

Note that reads and writes to variables of a reference type are observably atomic, so we know that setting the variable to `null` won't result in an invalid reference; the first thread will either observe the original reference or `null`, there is no "read a garbage reference" possibility.